What does the intercept mean in a model where the predictor is substance use at baseline and the outcome is substance use over time?
Long title I know, but I didn't know how else to ask it. I have a binomial regression model where the outcome is days of amphetamine use in the previous 28 days, i.e. a bounded count, with a maximum of 28 and a minimum of zero. This is measured multiple times throughout the first year of treatment. I want to estimate the influence of number of days of amphetamine use in the 28 days prior to start of treatment/baseline on rate of change in amphetamine use. So I am using the baseline measure of the outcome as a predictor.  This is the output from a mixed-effects regression. ats_baseline is the time-invariant numeric predictor, days of use in the 28 days prior to baseline. yearsFromStart is the indicator variable, indicating how many years from start of treatment each measure of amphetamine use was made, and then the interaction term. The coefficients are log-odds.
Regression Coefficients:
                            Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI 
Intercept                      -4.39      0.16    -4.70    -4.09 
ats_baseline                    0.27      0.02     0.24     0.31 
yearsFromStart                  0.59      0.20     0.19     0.98 
ats_baseline:yearsFromStart    -0.32      0.04    -0.39    -0.25 

Happy to be contradicted on this but it looks like, when averaged across different levels of amphetamine use, the log-odds of amphetamine use on any given day increase over time (increase in log-odds of 0.59 [CI: 0.19, 0.98] each year). Also each additional day of amphetamine use at baseline was associated with a reduction in change in log-odds of 0.32 per year (CI: -0.39, -0.25).
What confuses me is the intercept. The intercept is estimated log-odds of using amphetamine on a given day at baseline for someone who used no amphetamines in the 28 days prior to starting treatment. This does not make much sense to me. Nor does the ats_baseline coefficient, which, please correct me here, is estimated increase in log-odds of using amphetamines on any given day at baseline for every 1-day increase in number of days amphetamine use at baseline?
This all feels very recursive to me. Is this analysis kosher? If not, what would be a better way to do it? This post discusses the issue but does not explicitly discuss the meaning of the coefficients.
Any advice much appreciated

Do you mean a negative binomial regression? Because it sounds like your response is a count (number of days). In general, it could help if you described your model in a little more detail.

No just binomial regression. It is a bounded count: number of days used in the previous 28-day period. It can be measured at any time during the first year of treatment but is always a count with a maximum of 28

In your model, the intercept is the expected value of the outcome on the log-odds scale (assuming that this is appropriate for your model) when all covariates are set to zero. That is, it represents the estimated log-odds of using amphetamines for subjects with 0 days of use at baseline (ats_baseline = 0) at baseline time (yearsFromStart = 0), and is only relevant for such subjects.
Also note that, when a variable is involved in an interaction, its regression coefficient estimate is conditional on the other variable (that it is interacted with) being held at zero. So, the coefficient for ats_baseline (0.27) represents the log-odds change in amphetamine use for each additional day of amphetamine use in the 28 days prior to baseline at baseline (yearsFromStart = 0).
Likewise for yearsFromStart: its coefficient (0.59) represents the log-odds change in amphetamine use for each year of treatment, holding ats_baseline at 0.

Thank you @Robert Long. It looks like my interpretation of the intercept and ats_baseline coefficients was ok. Thank you for correcting my interpretation of the yearsFromStart coefficient, reminding me that it is conditioned on subjects who used 0 days amphetamine at baseline. Do you have any opinion on my question about the recursiveness of the intercept term (the 'at baseline at baseline' in both of our interpretations)? You didn't voice strong objections in your answer so I assume you don't think it is egregiously nonsensical?

You're very welcome, I'm glad it helped. To be honest, I don't quite understand your concern about recursiveness. The intercept isn’t recursive; it's just a reference point for both time and baseline covariate values. It sets the starting condition for a specific group - those with no baseline amphetamine use. From there, the predictors modify the outcome relative to this baseline. I don’t have any concerns, but if you'd like to explain in more detail, please feel free to post a new question, and ping me in this thread. I'd be happy to take a look

Ok. I will happily take your word for it.

Robert's post appropriately interprets the coefficients for you. If you would like them to have more meaning, then you may consider centering the predictor variables such that 0 is some meaningful number.
With a time variable, it can make sense to code it such that 0 is baseline. But if something happened in the experiment at day 15, for example, you might subtract 15 from the current variable such that the 0 value for time is at day 15.
With the other variable, which we know nothing about, you can do the same thing. What would be a meaningful value? Some people choose the mean or the median, and then subtract that value from the variable. In that case, 0 represents a case/person who has the mean or median value of that variable.
You should employ packages such as marginaleffects or ggefects to help you visualize the interaction, no matter whether you center the variables or not. Interactions can be tricky to understand under the best of circumstances.

Good points Erik (+1)
